# Trying to access array data that has been .emit and unable to

Tags: javascript, arrays, socket.io

On my websites load I am querying a database and retrieving rows.

However I am unable to access this comment_data

```
function onLoad(socket) {
    var connection = mysql.createConnection(db_access);
    connection.connect(function(err){
      if(err){
        console.log('Error connecting to Db');
        return;
      }
      console.log('Connection established');
    });

    var q = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM chat ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 8) chat ORDER BY id ASC";

    connection.query(q, function (err, results) {
        if (err) throw err;

        //io.sockets = emit to all
        io.sockets.emit("onLoad_comment", {
            load_comment_data: new Array(results[0],results[1],results[2],results[3],results[4],results[5],results[6],results[7])
        });

        connection.end();
    });
}
```

I handle the data with

```
socket.on('onLoad_comment', function (data) {
    for (i=0; i< data.load_comment_data.length; i++) {
        alert(data.load_comment_data[0].nick);
        //var content = '<div class="msgln"><div class="chat_prof_pic"><a href="' + data.comment_data[i].url + '"><img src="' + data.comment_data[i].pic + '"></a></div><div class="chat_msg"><b>' + data.comment_data[i].nick + '</b>';
        //content += ' ' + data.comment_data[i].comment + '</div></div><hr>';
        //$('#chatbox').append(content);
        //content = '';
    }
});
```

I have tried

1. data.load_comment_data[0].nick
2. data.load_comment_data[0][0]

But I just can't access the numbers.. however doing data.load_comment_data.length as part of the for loops returns the correct number so 'something' is being sent.

if I do

```
console.log(Array(results[0],results[1],results[2],results[3],results[4],results[5],results[6],results[7]));
```

I get:

```
[ { id: 3,
    sender: 'K1LzR',
    sender_pic: 'https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/d8/d85a3b326846fa2b0f6e59acdbaa0cfef307bd87_full.jpg',
    sender_url: 'http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198124567784/',
    message: '\n3',
    created_at: Thu Mar 31 2016 10:49:51 GMT-0700 (PDT) },
  { id: 4,
    sender: 'K1LzR',
    sender_pic: 'https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/d8/d85a3b326846fa2b0f6e59acdbaa0cfef307bd87_full.jpg',
    sender_url: 'http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198124567784/',
    message: '\n4',
    created_at: Thu Mar 31 2016 10:49:51 GMT-0700 (PDT) },
  { id: 5,
    sender: 'K1LzR',
    sender_pic: 'https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/d8/d85a3b326846fa2b0f6e59acdbaa0cfef307bd87_full.jpg',
    sender_url: 'http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198124567784/',
    message: '\n5',
    created_at: Thu Mar 31 2016 10:49:52 GMT-0700 (PDT) },
  { id: 6,
    sender: 'K1LzR',
    sender_pic: 'https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/d8/d85a3b326846fa2b0f6e59acdbaa0cfef307bd87_full.jpg',
    sender_url: 'http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198124567784/',
    message: '\n6',
    created_at: Thu Mar 31 2016 10:49:52 GMT-0700 (PDT) },
  { id: 7,
    sender: 'K1LzR',
    sender_pic: 'https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/d8/d85a3b326846fa2b0f6e59acdbaa0cfef307bd87_full.jpg',
    sender_url: 'http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198124567784/',
    message: '\n7',
    created_at: Thu Mar 31 2016 10:49:52 GMT-0700 (PDT) },
  { id: 8,
    sender: 'K1LzR',
    sender_pic: 'https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/d8/d85a3b326846fa2b0f6e59acdbaa0cfef307bd87_full.jpg',
    sender_url: 'http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198124567784/',
    message: '\n8',
    created_at: Thu Mar 31 2016 10:49:53 GMT-0700 (PDT) },
  { id: 9,
    sender: 'K1LzR',
    sender_pic: 'https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/d8/d85a3b326846fa2b0f6e59acdbaa0cfef307bd87_full.jpg',
    sender_url: 'http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198124567784/',
    message: 'test',
    created_at: Thu Mar 31 2016 11:25:16 GMT-0700 (PDT) },
  { id: 10,
    sender: 'Denilsonjvv',
    sender_pic: 'https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/fe/fef49e7fa7e1997310d705b2a6158ff8dc1cdfeb_full.jpg',
    sender_url: 'http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198294181499/',
    message: 'fesfse',
    created_at: Thu Mar 31 2016 12:48:56 GMT-0700 (PDT) } ]
```

Comment: when you are creating the object you call it `comment_data` and then you are trying to access it by `load_comment_data`

Comment: Sorry not sure how that copied wrong. It currently is load_comment_data for both; otherwise the for loop wouldn't work as atm it just alerts undefined 8 times

Comment: why not set it like : `load_comment_data: results`?

Comment: How would i access it on the client after being .emit?

Comment: Are you sure you have a nick column? In your alert, you use `0` for the index instead of `i`.

Comment: I am just using 0 to debug and see what method I can use to access the data. as you can see if the commented out parts i have used [i].

Comment: the client would see it as `data.load_comment_data` which you could iterate through the same way. `data.load_comment_data[i].nick`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107899/discussion-between-trex005-and-matt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have `nick` in your results data.  Try using `sender` instead.